# Solidity modifier attachment expression onlyOwner vs onlyOwner() | any difference?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, modifiers

Can I use onlyOwner() and onlyOwner modifier calls interchangeably in Solidity?

Is there any particular difference between these 2 functions below considering that

```
address owner;

constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}
```

2 different ways of attaching the modifier:

```
function buyPet(uint petId) external onlyOwner() {
        // ... some logic
 }




function buyPet(uint petId) external onlyOwner {
        // ... some logic
 }
```

Please advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are the same, brackets are more often used when we need to pass arguments to the modifier. Else normally we don't use brackets.